# Issue with recursion

Tags: java, list, recursion

I am trying to do a questions in Java which involves taking a Lisp List and a integer, and multiplies all the items in the list by the integer but it has to use recursion. This is my code:

```
public static LispList<Integer> multipy(LispList<Integer> ls, int m){
    LispList<Integer> ls1 = LispList.empty();
    if(ls.isEmpty()){
        return ls1;
    }else{
        ls1.cons(ls.head() * b);
    }
    return multipy(ls1, m)
}
```

My idea was to first create a empty list, ls1. I then use a base case where I check whether the original list - ls - is empty and if so, to return the new List, ls1. If it isnt empty, I then multiply all items by the integer and pass it into ls1. I then call the method again at the end.

However my issue is this wont work as it will create a new List ls1 each time, thus destroying the list already created. I thought about passing in ls1 into the recursive call but this dosent work either as it operates on ls1 and not ls as required. Is there a way around this or do I have to use a iterative method to do it?

Comment: You don't seem to define a variable called `ls2`.. does this code compile? Also what exactly is `LispList`?.. show the code.

Comment: Sorry, it should say ls1, not ls2 - I will change that now. A LispList is a special type of list that my course uses to teach recursion - full code can be found here - https://pastebin.com/WNU2A97a

Answer (score 1):

`multiply(ls.tail(),m)` gets you a list which contains all the values of the tail of `ls` multiplied. To that list you only have to add the head of `ls` multiplied, which you seem to do with the `cons()` method. So, it would be something like:

```
public static LispList<Integer> multipy(LispList<Integer> ls, int m){
     // No point making the else case if your
     // last statement of the block is a return
     if(ls.isEmpty()) return LispList.empty();

     return multiply(ls.tail(),m).cons(ls.head()*m);
}
```

I'm assuming your `LispList` has a `tail()` method.

Comment: Pretty close...only thing is that `LispList`s don't have a method `.multiply`. You probably meant `ls1.cons(multiply(...))` (in a new `ls1`).

Comment: @JCOC611 Right. Fixed my answer. Not sure if what you suggest is right, because i assume the cons operator receives an element, and if your element is the result of a `multiply()`, which is a list, you would get lists of lists and not a plain list.

Comment: No - dosent compile - it says "; expected" at the end of (ls.tail(), m)).

Comment: @AndréSantos yeah that makes sense...only missing removing the extra `)`.

Comment: @JCOC611 Fixed again, should work now :) Tassos, try now :)